# Multi-threading availability in Python

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

I've read many posts and articles about how to use `threading` in conjunction with `queue.Queue` or `multiprocessing.pool.ThreadPool` or `concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor`, but none of them work for me. And by that I mean that there's no parallelism at all. The only way I get 100% CPU usage and real parallelism is with `multiprocessing.Pool`. I also read about GIL and CPython.

Why do I care if at least one approach works? Well, `multiprocessing.Pool` simply prevents nested parallelism (daemonic processes). I can't have an outer function running in a separate process and that function start its own pool of processes.

So I have two questions to hopefully stop my never-ending search for an approach that works:

1. Is multi-threading really impossible in Python if I'm using the default Anaconda's distribution and its `python.exe`? (I see a bunch of articles talking about multi-threading with GUIs and I/O operations...)
2. Is nested parallelism really impossible in Python?

Answer (score 1):

> **Q** : *"Is **multi-threading** really impossible in Python...?"*

Lexicaly, there is a multi-threaded code-execution ( the code imports thread-based tools ).

Nevertheless, as you have read GIL-details and as of the as-is state of the Python interpreter design ( this is valid since ever and still defended by Guido van Rossum himself as a by-design property in 2020-Q2 ) the central lock-acquisition of the GIL-lock singleton, the actual code-execution gets re-**`[SERIAL]`**-ised, under the thread-based python tools, so the actual resulting performance speedup gets **`<< 1`** ( all add-on costs of all setups were paid, all GIL-lock related switching of threads' execution overheads are gotten to be paid ( each about `250 ms` - so add it up... ) during whole the course of the code-execution, yet, no acceleration could ever appear here ( except from the use-cases that happen to mask ( best as many times as possible, to justify all the other add-on costs ) some **external I/O-latency** ( network transports, *slow* user-interactions with UI ) **`>> 250 ms`**, that have been mentioned above too ) )

> **Q** : *"Is nested parallelism **really impossible** in Python?"*

Well, the ultimate answer is not about ***Is it* <sub>somehow</sub> *possible***,
but
***Does it make some sense to try to achieve that?***,
for which a plain answer ( still valid in 2020-Q2 )
<sub>(performance-wise)</sub> No, sorry, it would never make sense to try to do that,
**unless a sum of all the [add-on Costs](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/18374629/3)** at least starts to become **justified** (which it does not seem to be anywhere near in 2020-Q2 and hardly will start to be, unless a Python ecosystem undergoes a total redesign, going straight against the Guido's evangelisation).

A performance motivated architecture must well balance all add-on costs, so as not to fall into the [trap of the Amdahl's Law](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/18374629/3) - it is never paying way more than will ever get receiving back.

That simple to type.

So complex to achieve.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time. But I still don't understand why there are so many posts and articles teaching people how to achieve parallelism through multi-threading, if that's not supported. Unless they're assuming it's not CPython (e.g., PyPy seems to support it, I haven't tried it), but I rarely see that disclaimer being mentioned.